# How to use routing with module instead of component in Angular 10+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I successfully used component in routing but when i am using module instead of component in angular 10  i am getting a white screen.

I would be really thankful for any kind of help.

this is what i've been trying:
app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardModule } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.module';

import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: () => DashboardModule }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Dashboard module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Dashboard Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 
    alert('asdf');  
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: According to the doc (https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules), In Angular 10, lazy loading should be written like this : `loadChildren: () => import(./components/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)`

Comment: Yes first i have tried that but it did not work so i tried this way, though in both cases i am seeing a white screen with ERROR Error undefined in console log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy loaded feature modules have to have their child routes declared separately. For example:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
      },
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Also make sure to always load lazy modules like Emilien said before :)

```
loadChildren: () => import('./components/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
```

Comment: Thanks Raimo johanson & Emilien